# Website opening in _IECreate but not in _IECreateEmbedded

Tags: autoit

I am working on an AutoIt script which gets data from a website (in background). This website opens fine via `_IECreate()` but says `Invalid Browser` via `_IECreateEmbedded()`. The thing I have found is that this site requires Internet Explorer 11.

In windows 7 it does not work even in `_IECreate()` (but after updating my Internet Explorer I am able to do this). Is there any way to update IE version for `_IECreateEmbedded()`?

Answer (score 1):

`_IECreateEmbedded` uses IE7 compatibility mode by default.

There are two solutions.

**META TAG**

If you are the owner of the website you are automating, add this to meta tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

**Setting compatibility mode in registry using [this udf](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/163492-ie-embedded-control-versioning-use-ie9-and-html5-in-a-gui/)**

```
#include "IE_EmbeddedVersioning.au3"
;Get Current IE Embeddable Control Version (from ieframe.dll)
Local $sIEVer = _IE_EmbeddedGetVersion(), $nIEVer = @extended
ConsoleWrite("Embedded Version = " & $sIEVer & ", as Int: " & $nIEVer & ", @error = " & @error & @CRLF)

;Current Browser Emulation Mode for this executable (if exists)
Local $nIEBEVer = _IE_EmbeddedGetBrowserEmulation()
ConsoleWrite("GetEmbeddedVersion: " & $nIEBEVer & ", @error = " & @error & ", @extended = " & @extended & @CRLF)

;Set Browser Emulation Mode for this executable (if not already set or set to a different version)
;HKCU Branch:
_IE_EmbeddedSetBrowserEmulation()
;HKLM Branch:
;~ _IE_EmbeddedSetBrowserEmulation(-1, True, True)
```